# Interpolated values for specific missing indices of DataFrame or Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

With a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'key':  1, 'value': 0.4},
    {'key':  4, 'value': 0.5},
    {'key':  6, 'value': 0.7},
    {'key': 10, 'value': 1.3},
    {'key': 11, 'value': 1.4},
    {'key': 13, 'value': 1.1},
])
df.set_index('key', inplace=True)
```

I'd like to extract values that are either in the dataframe, or should be interpolated from existing values.

I'm aware of `DataFrame.interpolate()` and it's perfect for quickly computing interpolated values for indices with `NaN` values. So, an approach could be to add all the indices that aren't already in the index, sort the dataframe by index, interpolate and then extract the values again. Something like:

```
import numpy as np

new_rows = pd.DataFrame([
    {'key': index, 'value': np.nan} for index in indices if index not in df.index
])
new_rows.set_index('key', inplace=True)
result = df.append(new_rows).sort_index().interpolate(method='spline', order=2)

print(result['value'][indices])
```

Result:

```
key
3     0.529559
6     0.700000
9     1.073190
12    1.252086
15    1.369036
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

However, the whole process of creating an additional dataframe, appending it to the original, sorting by index, calling `.interpolate()` on the whole result and then extracting the required values seems to be a lot more complication than what I'd expected to find.

Something like:

```
# fictional, doesn't exist:
result = df.interpolated(indices)  # a DataFrame with only the rows for given indices, interpolated as needed
print(result['value'])
```

Or:

```
# fictional, doesn't exist:
result = df['value'].interpolated(indices)  # perhaps only on a Series
print(result)
```

Am I missing something obvious and is similar functionality actually available? Or is my approach above actually close to what the best way to do it would be?

After posting, I found a somewhat nicer approach myself, but would still like to hear if someone knows of a more efficient, pythonic or simpler approach:

```
indices = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]


def interpolated(df, indices, *args, **kwargs):
    for index in indices:
        if index not in df.index:
            df = df.append(pd.Series(name=index))
    return df.sort_index().interpolate(*args, **kwargs).loc[indices]


print(interpolated(df, indices, 'spline', order=2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy's `interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

interp = interp1d(df.index, df, axis=0)

interp([3,6,9])
```

Output (I duplicated the `value` column):

```
array([[0.46666667, 0.46666667],
       [0.7       , 0.7       ],
       [1.15      , 1.15      ]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not bad - if nobody is able to provide a clean and simple `pandas` solution, I'll accept this as the answer, as it certainly meets the need if adding `scipy` is not a problem.